# Too much space when using the Display Math Mode with the Theorem Environment

Tags: equations, theorems, amsthm

So I'd quite like to include the Display Math Mode (rather than just doing things inline so that they are bigger) within the theorem environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\begin{prop}
    \begin{equation*}
     [![\left\lVert \integral{f_n}{\mu}][1]][1] 
\right\rVert \leq \integral{\left\lVert f_n \right\rVert}{\mu} .
    \end{equation*}
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

However doing this yields the following (albeit with different numbering):

[image]

There there is too much space between the words Proposition and the Proposition statement for my liking. Is there any way to reduce the space, or ideally to include the Proposition statement in the same line as the equation, while still using the equation and theorem environments? Thanks!

Comment: with `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` you initiate a display math-mode. Did you try `\( \)` for inline math-mode??

Comment: Well I would like to use display math mode, because it makes my equation more readable.

Comment: ordinarily, the display is limited to the math.  the text "Given step functions" would be run-in after the theorem heading.  you are going against decades, if not centuries, of math publishing tradition.

Comment: then your statement "given step functions" can be outside of the equation environment.. Actually i cannot find any reason to include it into your equation

Comment: @Yorgos, I've edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: @Yorgos Yeah that's true, I've edited this to make it clearer.

Comment: What is your code supposed to result in? In particular, I don't understand the `[1][1]`, and the brackets.

Comment: @Bernard - I think`[![` and `][1]][1]` are left-overs from an earlier, unsuccessful attempt to post a screenshot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\(..\)` to get inline usage; however, explicitly request `\displaystyle` to get display style within the inline usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\begin{prop}
    \(\displaystyle
     \left\lVert \int{f_n}{d\mu} 
\right\rVert \leq \int{\left\lVert f_n \right\rVert}{d\mu} .
    \)
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have one of these in-line equations, which I find quite readable. I took the opportunity to simplify the code for the norm, using `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand\integral[2]{\int #1\,\mathrm{d}\mkern1mu #2}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\begin{prop}
\quad \(\displaystyle
     \norm*{\integral{f_n}{\mu}} \leq \integral{\norm*{f_n}}{\mu} .
    \)
\end{prop}

\begin{prop}
\hfill \(\displaystyle
     \integral{\norm*{f_n}}{\mu}\geq \norm*{\integral{f_n}{\mu}}.
    \) \hfill\null
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to make the body of the proposition, which consists of a formula, in-line with the proposition's header, it's perfectly alright to use inline math rather than display math:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
 $\norm[\big]{ \int f_n\,d\mu} \leq\int\norm{f_n}\,d\mu$.
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```